# How to Solve Memory Error in Arduino?

Tags: windows, memory, arduino

Everytime I verify my code, this error comes out...

Sketch uses `4760 bytes` (14%) of program storage space. Maximum is `32256 bytes`.

Global variables use `268 bytes` (13%) of dynamic memory, leaving `1780 bytes` for local variables. Maximum is `2048 bytes`.

I am using **Windows 8.1** with **Arduino 1.8.2**.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error.  That is the message that it gives on a successful compile.  Your next step is to upload that to the board and see if it works.